# Problem with SDK amazon-cognito-identity-js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am starting with aws-cognito. I have created a UserPool and a UserPoolClient on the Amazon platform. I am implementing a lambda (as a test) that performs the registration of a user. But trying to run it with the postman returns "Internal Server Error". This is the code of my Lambda.

```
module.exports.register = async event => {

  var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
  var CognitoUserPool = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;

  var poolData = {
    UserPoolId: '...', // Here, I put my UserPoolId
    ClientId: '...' // Here, I put my ClientId
  };
  var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
  var attributeList = [];

  var dataEmail = {
    Name: 'email',
    Value: 'myemail@gmail.com'
  };

  var dataPhoneNumber = {
    Name: 'phone_number',
    Value: '+15555555555'
  };
  var attributeEmail = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
  var attributePhoneNumber = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);

  attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
  attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);
  var cognitoUser = ''
  userPool.signUp('myemail@gmail.com', 'MyPassword7.com', attributeList, null, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      cognitoUser = err;
    }
    cognitoUser = result.user;
  });
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
        input: event,
        cognitoUser: cognitoUser
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };
```

Comment: can you look at cloudwatch logs of that lambda and see if there are any errors?
if not then it is likely content-type mismatch

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the proper headers in your response

```
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
```